# Multi-platform Desktop application frameworks using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html, desktop-application

What's the best framework for creating Multi platform desktop app using web technologies such as HTML, JavaScript, and CSS, I would like to know the complexity (learning rate) and flexibility of each one as much as the future promise of each one ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it could be **Electron.**

[image]

> f you can build a website, you can build a desktop app. Electron is a framework for creating native applications with web technologies like JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. It takes care of the hard parts so you can focus on the core of your application.

In fact, there is a lot of applications made using web technologies (HTML/JS):

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can take a look at https://electron.atom.io/

Answer (score 2):

I would like to recommend to you https://electron.atom.io/

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way of creating javascript apps that run on the desktop perfectly well without requiring the complexities of node.js or electron is to use the Xwidget engine or the yahoo widget engine. Both engines use ECMA standard javascript so any web app can be ported and vice versa. The output goes to objects whose screen position and other properties are described in XML.

The javascript code in both engines is compatible, each having its own quirks with regard to how the objects are displayed but the logic is the same in both.

Xwidget engine uses Microsoft's jscript, the Yahoo engine uses an earlier version of the ECMA script standard. Both have APIs that allow access to o/s functions that standard javascript simply does not - this is a real boon. They both have on-the-fly debuggers that allow rapid application development, Xwidget has its own IDE (not the best but it'll do in a pinch).

Both engines have access to Windows activeX allowing you even more access to the Windows sub systems, FS, WMI, WMP &c

The Yahoo widget engine is abandonware but still functions and is likely to do so for the foreseeable future. Xwidgets is still supported but the IDE and support is generally flaky. Yahoo widget is mature and comes with full documentation.

I created very complex apps for the desktop here:
[Steampunk javascript apps](http://yereverluvinuncleber.deviantart.com/gallery/59981269/yahoo-widgets)

They are over the top but your apps would be much easier to create.

The good thing about using these engines is that if you do all your logic in pure javascript if either of these engines goes tits-up then your code can still be migrated to the the web.

Good luck to you in your search.